# Modify default number of admin model inlines?

Tags: django, django-admin

Currently, when creating new items, I'm always given three inlines by default for all of my inline editors. Is there  a way to specify a different number of inlines by default?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the inline class, specify `extra`:

```
class EmailInline(models.TabularInline):
    model = Email
    extra = 1
```